# Android scaled bitmap signature into pdf

Tags: java, android, canvas, bitmap

i couldn't find anything for my problem.

My problem is this. I have to create a pdf with a signature. I don't have problems to create pdf or to create signature but when i put them together, i resize the signature to be smaller but the quality of the signature is been reduced.

Here I show you the signature and the scaled signature.

[create signature](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iTGGi.png)

[scaled signature](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xLuCW.png)

This is how i create the bitmap of the signature.

```
   mSignaturePad = (SignaturePad) dialog.findViewById(R.id.signature_pad);

   Bitmap signaturePad = mSignaturePad.getSignatureBitmap();

   createPDF(signaturePad);
```

This is how i create the canvas of the pdf page.

```
   PdfDocument.Page page = document.startPage(pageInfo);

   Canvas canvas = page.getCanvas();
```

And finally i draw the bitmap after i obtain the scaled bitmap.

```
   int width = source.getWidth();
   int height = source.getHeight();

   float scaleWidth = ((float) 100) / width;
   float scaleHeight = ((float) 140) / height;
   Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
   matrix.postScale(scaleWidth, scaleHeight);
   matrix.postRotate(-90);

   Bitmap scaledBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(source, 0, 0, width, height, matrix, true);

   Paint paint = new Paint();
   paint.setAntiAlias(true);
   paint.setFilterBitmap(true);
   paint.setDither(true);

   canvas.drawBitmap(scaledBitmap, 387, 717, paint3);
```

This is not the only way that i have tested to scale bitmap. I tested many ways but nothing worked. How can i scale this bitmap?

I hope you can help me. Thank you.

psd: Sorry for my english.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The below explains how to add a image from assets folder. If you have the bitmap already, then no issue just follow it from the bitmap process. you can also follow the [Example](http://www.mysamplecode.com/2013/05/android-itext-pdf-bluetooth-printer.html).

```
File myFile1 = new File("/sdcard/ourdata/" + pdfname + ".pdf");
myFile1.createNewFile();
Document pdfDoc = new Document();
PdfWriter docWriter = PdfWriter.getInstance(document,
        new FileOutputStream(myFile1));
document.open();
PdfContentByte cb = docWriter.getDirectContent();
InputStream inputStream = getAssets().open("signature.png");
Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream);
ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);
Image signature = Image.getInstance(stream.toByteArray());
signature.setAbsolutePosition(400f, 150f);
signature.scalePercent(25f);
document.add(signature);
```